# displaying an image stored in a PHP variable into html script

Tags: java, php, html, css

I am doing a mini project in PHP for video streaming . Where in i have done with all coding but i am stuck in UI . I am supposed to display all the videos along with its name and a picture of it. I can display all the names easily using 'echo' but how do i display it picture using HTML script?

This is the part of program where i get errors

```
enter code here

    <?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `video`");
?>
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br />";
}
<div class="wrapper col4">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <h2>Gallery Category Title</h2>
      <ul>

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
     {<?php
    $id = $row['id'];
    $imag = $row['img'];
$name = $row['name'];
<li><a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="$imag.jpeg" title="Image 2"> <img src="$imag.jpeg" alt="Title Text" /> </a>
<a href= 'watch.php?id=$id'> '$name'  </a> </li></br>
echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br />";
?>
```

Comment: what sort of videos..? from online source or locally stored...?

Answer (score 0):

Try it, I used this type of code. If video id locally stored on database.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `video`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $imag = $row['img'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo '<a href="watch.php?id='.$id.'">'.$name.'</a><br />';
}
?>
<div class="wrapper col4">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <h2>Gallery Category Title</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="<?php echo''.$imag.jpeg.'';?>" title="Image 2"> <img src="<?php echo''.$imag.jpeg.'';?>" alt="Title Text" /> </a><a href= "watch.php?id=<?php echo''.$id.'';?>"><?php echo''.$name.'';?>"</a></li></br>
<?php
      echo '<a href="watch.php?id='.$id.'">'.$name.'</a><br />';
?>
     </ul>
```

Comment: but i dont want to display image using echo but want to put it in imgsrc of my HTML script ...

Comment: I am not clear what you want, updated my HTML with PHP.  Why you don't want to using echo?  Are you just want to display image name? Can you give/upload here a picture about your requirement and problem area?

Comment: This is my simple page without any layout                <?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','','test');
mysql_select_db("try");

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Video Streaming in intranet</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `video`");
echo mysql_error();
if($query)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{


 $id = $row['id'];
 $name = $row['name'];
 
 echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br />";
}
}
else
{

}
?>

</body>
</html>

Comment: This is my html file where I hav to display the images <div class="wrapper col4">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <h2>Gallery Category Title</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="../images/demo/gallery/500x500.gif" title="Image 1"><img src="../images/demo/gallery/174x174.gif" alt="Title Text" /></a></li>
        <li><a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="../images/demo/gallery/500x500.gif" title="Image 2"><img src="../images/demo/gallery/174x174.gif" alt="Title Text" /></a></li>

Comment: You should update your above code for better view. And please clear me what u want to do?

Comment: Here's my project desc : 1) user select upload option and uploads a video 2) Along the video i m even asking for a pic or thumbail to be displayed, I am using my sql db which stores img location and video location ie url of it.  3) If user wants to watch a video he will be shown all the images and its names and if he selects any image or the name the video will be streamed. As far my work i can show the name but not the image on that html page as it won't allow me to put tags <> inside php script.

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`video`");                       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$id = $row['id'];
 $name = $row['name'];
 $imurl=$row['img'];                                                                     echo "<a href='watch.php?id=$id'>$name</a><br >";    this is how I display the name on the screen

Comment: $imurl , Is it your image name with extension (jpeg, gif, jpg)?